# Likelihood of getting a certain sum after rolling several six-sided dice

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

> Do you believe your friend whom claims to achieve a sum of $400$ after
> rolling $100$ six-sided dice?

I was asked this question in a data science interview, and I was wondering if someone can please explain if my reasoning understanding is correct now. I think the answer is no, I shouldn't believe them. By the normal approximation to the binomial distribution, I found that the probability of getting a sum of 400 which is less than 1/501, which is the "average" probability of the 501 outcomes.

Is my reasoning okay? Or is there something wrong with it.

Comment: $p=0.002$, `sum(replicate(1e6,sum(sample(1:6,100,replace=TRUE)))>=400)/1e6`. SCNR.

Comment: Isn't that the probability of getting more than $400$? Not $400$ exactly?

Comment: You should go work for another company

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The exact outcome of 400 isn't the relevant quantity for evaluating the plausibility of the claim; as you add more dice, even the most probable outcomes will become extremely improbable on their own, so it's not the probablility of that exact outcome that tells you about how consistent it is with the apparent circumstances (that some outcome is plausible on a large number of fair dice).
2. The binomial doesn't seem to be directly relevant, so you probably wouldn't do yourself any favours mentioning it. Even if it was relevant it's not clear from your post how you got to 1/501 from the binomial. It sounds like you switched to treating the sum on 100 dice as a discrete uniform (which would suggest what are perhaps even worse misunderstandings than thinking it was binomial).

If my numerical convolution didn't lose too much accuracy from moving piles of sand, it looks like the probability for $\geq 400$ from direct calculation is about $0.00182$ (normal approximation with continuity correction is about $0.00187$).

However, in an interview I'd just compute the standard deviation (var = 3500/12 is a little under 300, so just to a rough approximation, sd is around 17),  and say "The total will be approximately normal. Now 400 is almost 3 sd's from the mean of 350. If the dice were fair a value at least this far from the mean would be pretty unlikely". Done.

Here's the right half of the pmf (with the far upper tail cut off), with the normal approximation to those probabilities dotted in red:

[image: plot of pmf and normal approximation]

It's symmetric so I'm just showing half (allowing us to get a tiny bit more detail).

As we can see from the plot the normal approximation is going to work quite well. Convolutions of discrete uniforms settle in pretty quickly, apart from the far tail; 100 dice is plenty good enough to use a normal approximation for this sort of back of the envelope calculation.

If you don't know that the variance of the outcomes on a die with k sides is $\frac{k^2-1}{12}$ (so 35/12 for a six-sided die), you'd need to work it out, but it's not a long mental computation:

The sum of the first 6 squares is simple - $k(k+1)(2k+1)/6$ for $k=6$ gives $7\times 13=91$, so the variance is $91/6-(7/2)^2 = (182-147)/12 = 35/12$. (Though if I was doing this in my head, I'd work this slightly differently, in terms of squared deviations from the mean - $\frac16\cdot 2(\frac14+2\frac14+6\frac14)=35/12$.)

So then the sum of 100 dice has variance 3500/12 and you proceed by the earlier reasoning to the "nearly 3 sd's from the mean" (assuming you also know $17^2 =289$ and $18^2=324$, so the square root of something in the region of 290-300 is 17-and-a-bit; at worst you should definitely be able to say the sd is somewhere between 16 and 18 and still get to "roughly 3 sd's from the mean").

[The actual number of sd's is about 2.9 but we don't need to be that accurate to answer the question.]

Just with some basic number facts, the CLT, and knowing some basic things about the normal distribution you should be able to give a good answer quite quickly.

It doesn't much matter whether the probability calculation should be one or two tailed (both are quite small), but I'd probably mention that if you do two tailed you want to double $P(T\geq 400)$, but "it's still a very small number".

---

How is any of this relevant to this kind of job? I think it speaks to several things, but IMO, perhaps the most important is your ability to perform rapid ballpark reasonableness checks on your computations. If you have no idea how to approach these sorts of calculations, you're left accepting whatever output you got, which means at any given level of competence you're letting through a lot more errors than if you know how to say "wait, this makes no sense, let's check that calculation again".

Being able to identify a suitable quick approximation or bound and evaluate it is an essential everyday skill for anyone doing a lot of computation. People make errors all the time - of many kinds - but if you can catch a lot of them before it matters, the fact that you will make errors will hurt your employer much less - you weed a lot of them out.

Comment: It's not 100% clear from the question whether we should be evaluating "Probability of being at least this far from 350" or "Probability of being at least this far above 350". It depends on some things in the situation that have not been made clear - e.g. if it was a situation where high rolls would benefit my friend and low rolls would not, I'd do the second thing, though I'd lean toward doing the first if there was no further clarification -- but for the purpose of deciding whether we doubt the claim it won't make much difference since the probability will still be low either way.

Comment: We should also be clear that the low probability calls into doubt the basis on which the calculation was made (the fairness of the die); it doesn't directly imply that the claim itself is inaccurate, just that it's very unlikely with a fair die. I've bought dice (supposedly fair enough to use in games) that were clearly biased; I have one 20-sided one that as it nears the end of the rolling, speeds up and slows down and will regularly almost turn right angles - it's not evenly weighted (by accident, the manufacturer was trying to make a normal die).

Comment: You are of course completely right in your last two paragraphs. And I personally would completely bomb this kind of interview question. Yes, I'd be able to say that the p value must be tiny, but I'd really need time to figure the theory out - and I would honestly not see the point, since a single line of R gives me the answer, and is far less error prone than theory. I personally would accept any candidate that could write down that line of R (or Python or whatever), but I wonder whether the prospective employer would.

Comment: I'd certainly be inclined to accept that (correctly) writing a line of R that gets the answer in seconds would constitute a reasonable answer.